# libGDX unable to perform action

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I have a Letter class like this:

```
class Letter : Label {
    val char: Char
    var interactable = true
    constructor(char: Char) : super(""+char, H.letterStyle()) {
        this.char = char
    }

    fun animateSelect() {
        addAction(Actions.scaleTo(3.0f, 3.0f, 0.5f))
    }
    fun animateUnselect() {
        addAction(Actions.scaleTo(3.0f, 3.0f, 0.5f))
    }
}
```

In my touch listener, I have this:

```
override fun touchDown(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {

        var currentInteractingLetter: Letter? = null
        for (letter in letterList) {
            if (letter.bound.contains(x, y)) {
                currentInteractingLetter = letter
                break
            }
        }

        if (currentInteractingLetter == null) {

        } else {
            selectedLetters.add(currentInteractingLetter)
            currentInteractingLetter.animateSelect()
            currentInteractingLetter.interactable = false
        }

        return true
    }
```

The logic is quite straightforward. When user touch any one of the `letter`s, I will invoke `animateSelect()` function. 
When I run it, `animateSelect` did get called, but there is no `scaleUp` effect. I have tried to clear all actions before `addAction` but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels don't directly support scaling.

The easy way to solve this is put the label in a [Container](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#container), `setTransform(true)` on the Container, and add your scale action to the `Container`.

```
val container= Container<Label>().apply {
     isTransform=true
     actor=label          // Set your Label to container 
}

container.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(3.0f, 3.0f, 0.5f))
```